# Time complexity of randomized algorithm: right-multiplying by random elements $z_i$ from a group $H$ to achieve $H$-invariance

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, combinatorial-group-theory

<sup>**Note**: This question was inspired by a [related question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9222) about the [Quantum Merlin Arthur (QMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QMA) complexity class on Quantum Computing Stack Exchange. I was deliberating whether to ask this on CS Theory Stack Exchange or here on Math Overflow. I decided to go with Math Overflow as I suppose mathematicians would be more acquainted with results in computational group theory than computer science theorists. In case this is the wrong venue, feel free to let me know in a comment.</sup>

---

Suppose I have an element $g$ of a finite group $H$ (with a generator $\langle g_1, \ldots, g_k\rangle$). Now I choose a *random* element $z_1$ from $H$ and produce the elements $g, gz_1$ by right multiplication. In the second iteration, I choose another random element $z_2$, produce $g, gz_1, gz_2, gz_1z_2$ by right multiplication. I keep repeating this process until I produce a set of elements $S$ that is *invariant* under right multiplication.

Approximately, how many random elements $z_i$ do I need to choose before I can achieve this *right invariance* or at least, something exponentially close to right invariance)? I guess it's basically akin finding the time complexity of a randomized algorithm.

(If I'm not wrong, such *right invariance* would be achieved only when the entire group $H$ is generated. So perhaps a better name would be *$H$-invariance*.)

Would the scaling be expressible in terms of $k$ i.e., the number of generator elements $g_i$ of $H$? Moreover, would the result depend upon whether the group is commutative or not?

I believe this is a standard problem in **computational group theory**, but I'm not being able to figure out which one it is, from a basic Wikipedia search.  Please let me know if you know of any paper or other resources dealing with this kind of problem.

Comment: The answer depends on $H$. For an Abelian group of order $n$ you need approximately $n$ steps. For a group from an expander family like $SL_k(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ you need about $\log n$ steps. See the book by Lubotzky on expanders.

Comment: Use Google, search for expanders lubotzky random walk finite groups

Comment: You might like to check out Cooperman's Algorithm for something related.   I like Ben Green's notes on them: https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/TALKS/Green_Wigderson_lecture.pdf

Comment: I think implicitly you require each of $z_1,z_2,\cdots$ to be chosen from the generators $\langle g_1,\cdots,g_k\rangle$.  I think after $r$ iterations, there are $2^r$ different words that you have written and added to your set $S$, but if there are a lot of relations amongst $\langle g_1,\cdots,g_k\rangle$ then $S$ might only include much less than $2^r$ elements.